# Variables defined within a loop are not defined outside the loop (PHP)

Tags: php, loops, scope

I have a series of variables, I want to check if they are 0 or not, and if they are, I wish to redefine the variable to equal the string 'Unavailable'.

To do this I wrote a loop:

```
$indicators=array($admitted, $targeted, $cured, $defaulted, $total);

foreach($indicators as $indicator)
{   
if($indicator==0)
    {
    $indicator='Unavailable';
    }       
}
```

This checks to see if each of the variables in the array $indicators is equal to zero, and if so redefines it.

However, after this loop is closed a table is built using the variables:

```
$table1 .= '
            <tr>
                    <td>'.$year.'</td>
                    <td>'.$targeted.'</td>
                    <td>'.$admitted.'</td>
                    <td>'.$total.'</td>
                    <td>'.$cured.'</td>
                    <td>'.$defaulted.'</td>                 
            </tr>
            ';
```

The output of which includes some '0' terms - **they are never substituted for the string 'Unavailable'.**

I debugged the code with the following:

```
foreach($indicators as $indicator)
{
echo 'Before: '.$indicator;
if($indicator==0)
    {
    $indicator='Unavailable';
    }
    echo '<br />';
echo 'After :'.$indicator;
}
```

And confirmed that it was redefining the variables, but that redefiniton was not applying outside of the loop.

I feel this is an issue with scope - which I confess to not understanding well.

**My question is: how can I get the variables defined inside a loop to apply outside of that loop?**

Many thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because all you're doing is updating the variable `$indicator`, not the original elements of the array.

There are 2 ways of doing this. Either [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
foreach($indicators as &$indicator)
```

or manually push the change back to the array:

```
foreach($indicators as $idx => $indicator)
{   
    if($indicator==0)
    {
        $indicators[$idx]='Unavailable';
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about pass by reference before!

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the changed value back to array

try this

```
foreach($indicators as $key=>$indicator)
{   
 if($indicator==0)
   {
  $indicator[$key]='Unavailable';
  }       
}
```